optimizing the circuit depth of a quantum circuit while using Fake Hardware
I am trying to search some ways in qiskit==1.0 to reduce the circuit depth while using Fake HW.
What I understand is that changing the optimization level to 3 will reduce the circuit depth but I am not getting any benefit.
Is there some ways by which circuit depth of the circuit can be reduced by using some qiskit API since a lot of work is presently going in this field?
The code presently I am using is as below:
 backend = FakeKolkata()
 print("Circuit depth: ", qc_combine.depth())
 print("Circuit gate counts:", qc_combine.count_ops())
    
 pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=3) # changing 1 to 3
 qc_combine = pm.run(qc_combine)
 print("Optimzied circuit depth: ", qc_combine.depth())
 print("Optimized gate counts:", qc_combine.count_ops())
 print("Optimzied circuit depth: ", qc_combine.depth())
 print("Optimized gate counts:", qc_combine.count_ops())

 job = backend.run(qc_combine, shots= shots_used)
 result = job.result()
 counts = result.get_counts(qc_combine)


Circuit depth:  8
Circuit gate counts: OrderedDict([('ucry', 6), ('measure', 6), ('unitary', 1), ('barrier', 1)])

Optimzied circuit depth:  10243
Optimized gate counts: OrderedDict([('rz', 6430), ('sx', 4428), ('cx', 4298), ('x', 97), ('measure', 6), ('barrier', 1)])

Edit1
The below code is sample code which shows the process of circuit generation. It is a 3 qubit circuit as shown below:
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library import UCRYGate
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import  FakeKolkata
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
import math
num_qubits = 3
data = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
])
angles = [np.pi / 4, np.pi / 2, 3 * np.pi / 4, np.pi]
controls = [0, 1]
target = [2]

qr1 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name= 'q')
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(qr1)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)

qr2 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name='q')
qc2= QuantumCircuit(qr2)

qc2.unitary(data, qr2, label= 'u')

qc1 = qc1.compose(qc2, list(range(0, num_qubits)))
qc1.measure_all()


print(qc1.draw())
shots_used = 10000
print("Circuit depth: ", qc2.depth())
print("Circuit gate counts:", qc2.count_ops())

backend_fake = FakeKolkata()
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend_fake)
coupling_map = backend_fake.configuration().coupling_map
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator', noise_model = noise_model, coupling_map= coupling_map)

pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=3)
qc_optimized = pm.run(qc1)
print("Optimzied circuit depth: ", qc_optimized.depth())
print("Optimized gate counts:", qc_optimized.count_ops())
# pdb.set_trace()

job = backend.run(qc_optimized, noise_model = noise_model, shots = shots_used)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(qc_optimized)

Although, this approach of Fake hardware creates shallow circuit but I am not sure how long will it work.
The other approach of Fake Hardware is as below:
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library import UCRYGate
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import  FakeKolkata
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
import math
num_qubits = 3
data = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
])
angles = [np.pi / 4, np.pi / 2, 3 * np.pi / 4, np.pi]
controls = [0, 1]
target = [2]

qr1 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name= 'q')
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(qr1)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)

qr2 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name='q')
qc2= QuantumCircuit(qr2)

qc2.unitary(data, qr2, label= 'u')

qc1 = qc1.compose(qc2, list(range(0, num_qubits)))
qc1.measure_all()


print(qc1.draw())
shots_used = 10000
print("Circuit depth: ", qc2.depth())
print("Circuit gate counts:", qc2.count_ops())
backend_fake = FakeKolkata()
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend_fake, optimization_level=3) # changing 1 to 3
qc_optimized = pm.run(qc2)
print("Optimzied circuit depth: ", qc_optimized.depth())
print("Optimized gate counts:", qc_optimized.count_ops())

job = backend_fake.run(qc_optimized, shots= shots_used)
result = job.result()

Any qiskit API which optimize the circuit depth?

Technically, you can merge all the gates in your circuit into a single multi-quit gate, resulting in a circuit with a depth of 1. However, this is not likely what you have in mind. It seems your question could use more clarity.

Thank you for the response @MonteNero. I donot think it is possible to merge the circuit into a multiqubit gate because I am using a Fake Hardware as a backend.

I have edited the question to make it more clear @MonteNero.

What kind of circuit are you running? You can use Classiq engine to trade off between width and depth, or between error level and depth https://docs.classiq.io/latest/user-guide/synthesis/. It is not instead qiskit, because it choose optimal implementation+ transpiling with qiskit

@Manu. I think you are missing an important point. First and foremost you need to specify the gatesets you are working with. Transpilers will express your circuit in some desirable gateset (e.g. u1, u2, u3 etc) , but then, compilers will approximate the circuit into instructions gateset something like Cliff + T. As of now, it is hard to understand what you are asking. That is why, without these specifics, one can simply suggest to merge all gates into a single mega gate and that would be a depth 1 circuit. Of course, this is silly.

My originak circuit consists of ('ucry', 6), ('measure', 6), ('unitary', 1), ('barrier', 1)]. After transpilation, it gets converted into circuit consisting of [('rz', 6430), ('sx', 4428), ('cx', 4298), ('x', 97), ('measure', 6), ('barrier', 1)] by the qiskit. Yes, as you suggested, if the circuit is not broken into basis gates, you get good results with even Fake HW, but not sure that it can be considered as correct approach. Is there a way that some qiskit API can reduce the depth of circuit consisting of basis gates  because that circuit I can run on actual HW also @MonteNero.

Can you put the code you use to create your circuit please?

Thank you for the response @TristanNemoz. I have edited the question showing how the circuit is created. Going through this website, I could figure out there are two approaches to run code on  FakeHW in qiskit==1.0. Please review my question again.

Check out tket. It is also qiskit compatible.

Thank you for the response @RefikMansuroglu. I will study the API of tket used for compilation and optimization of quantum circuit.

It would be great if someone can provide some answer so that I can award the bounty because otherwise it will go waste.
